# GGTS not adding classes to Grails project

Tags: eclipse, git, grails

GGTS "Create Service" did not work for me. So I ran "grails create-service" from the command line and this worked. This has created the service class correctly, but now I can't see it under the Grails project in GGTS (Groovy/Grails Tool Suite).

I have attempted the following actions:

- I have right-clicked the project and clicked "Refresh"
- I have ran "grails clean" from the command line
- I have ran "grails integrate-with --eclipse" from the command line
- I have closed and reopened GGTS
- I have deleted the project from my workspace and reimported it again

Also, I can see controllers and domain under Project Explorer but not services. I can also use the CTRL Shift R shortcut to access the class.

How do I make new classes appear in my GGTS project?

Comment: Do you see the service in Grails view? Can you search for the class (CTRL+SHIFT+R) or corresponding in Mac?

Comment: I forgot to add I can see controller and domain but not services. I can also use CTRL Shift R to access the class.

Comment: If you access the class with ctrl-shift-r then click the "Link with Editor" button (the icon with two yellow arrows at the top of the project), what do you see?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but I was missing the "domain" folder in my project. The classes were available on the file system but not showing up in GGTS Project Explorer. (Using GGTS 3.5.1)

To fix it:
I opened the project properties, selected the "Java Build Path"; under the "Source" option I clicked the "Add Folder..." button. Next a "Source Folder Selection" dialog opened and I could see the "domain" folder was unselected. I selected it, clicked "Ok" and click "Ok" again on the "Properties" dialog.

[image: Properties and Source Selection dialogs]

Boom! Now I have my "domain" folder back.

[image: Domain Folder is back]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your project config is messed. Remove the project from GGTS.

Go into project folder and run the command

```
myproject> grails clean
myproject> grails integrate-with --eclipse
```

Read the project in GGTS using "Import existing project"